# Error installing global on Arch linux

Tags: archlinux

I was trying to install global from source. I run

```
./configure --with-exuberant-ctags=/usr/bin/ctags
```

and it runs OK. However, when I run

```
make
```

it gives the error

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o gtags-cscope gtags-cscope.o alloc.o basename.o 
build.o command.o display.o edit.o exec.o find.o help.o history.o input.o logdir.o mouse.o mygetenv.o mypop
en.o ../libparser/libgloparser.a ../libutil/libgloutil.a ../libdb/libglodb.a ../libglibc/libgloglibc.a -llt
dl -lncurses                                                                                              
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o gtags-cscope gtags-cscope.o alloc.o basename.o build.o command.o display.o edi
t.o exec.o find.o help.o history.o input.o logdir.o mouse.o mygetenv.o mypopen.o  ../libparser/libgloparser
.a ../libutil/libgloutil.a ../libdb/libglodb.a ../libglibc/libgloglibc.a -lltdl -lncurses                 
/usr/bin/ld: input.o: undefined reference to symbol 'erasechar'
/usr/lib/libtinfo.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:461: gtags-cscope] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pspencil/tmp/global-6.5.7/gtags-cscope'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:517: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pspencil/tmp/global-6.5.7'
make: *** [Makefile:424: all] Error 2
```

I have installed the package `ncurses` which apparently should provide the erase char symbol. I cannot find anything useful on Google.

Comment: I just got the same error today as well, on a project that compiles fine on another machine. Looking up libtinfo on the AUR has a few comments about the latest ncurses including libtinfo.so
Haven't got it to work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly link the `tinfo` library.
NCurses uses tinfo, from what I have read ncurses should include the tinfo functionality in it's own library, maybe this has changed recently.

Comment: Thank you so much! For others who have the same problem, you need to compile from source (I haven't figure out a way to change the build commands on AUR) and after configure, run `find . -name Makefile -exec sed -i -e "s/-lncurses/& -ltinfo/" {} \;` from the project root.